# Getting all versions of a Sitecore item. Regardless of Lifetime values

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to get all versions of an item using `Database.GetItem(...)`.

```
item.Versions.GetVersionNumbers();
```

returns three version (1, 2 and 3) as expected.

But

```
item.Versions.GetVersions()
```

returns an empty array.
It seems that the reason is that version 1 has Lifetime dates that does not include current date

```
db.GetItem(item.ID, item.Language, new Version(1)); //returns null
db.GetItem(item.ID, item.Language, new Version(2)); //returns the correct version as expected
db.GetItem(item.ID, item.Language, new Version(3)); //returns the correct version as expected
```

So the question is: How can I foreache through all versions of an item. Also the versions that has a lifetime span sometime in the past of future.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but have you tried pass `true` to `GetVersions()` method? just call `item.Versions.GetVersions(true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var versions = Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetVersions(item);
var allVersions = versions.Select(x => item.Database.Items[item.ID, item.Language, x]);
```